# Deploying new Apps via TestFlight

Tags: ios, certificate, testflight, software-distribution

I am following [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/BetaTestingTheApp.html) to deploy a new App to testers using TestFlight.

One of the steps says:

> Generate a new App Store Distribution profile containing the beta
>   entitlement to distribute builds via TestFlight.

However, when I create the distribution profile I am unable to see an option that specifically mentions "TestFlight".

Which options should I choose?

Comment: You can see prerelease option in iTunes Connect where can deploy build via testflight and set tester.

Comment: Thank you. I was struggling to find the right certificates, but I then realised that I was using a developer certificate to sign rather than a production certificate. That was the error that caused me to think that the distribution profile I was choosing was incorrect. Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create provision profile for App Store distribution, and use this provision profile to TestFlight distribution

[image]